# how to use modulo (%) to wrap characters

Tags: python, math, modulo

im trying to use mod in python but something is going wrong

my code:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        result += string[i]
        if i % max_width-1 == 0:
            result += '\n'
    
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

my input:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
4
```

my output:

```
AB
CDEF
GHIJ
KLMN
OPQR
STUV
WXYZ
```

but my expected output is:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
```

I couldn't find whats wrong, the debugger seems to give wrong results
ty

Comment: Looks like it does exactly what one would expect to me. Have you gone through the `%` calculation on paper to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: As an aside, instead of `string, max_width = input(), int(input())`, hard code these to test values for your example. That makes the example self-contained.

Comment: Alternatively: `def wrap(s, max_width): return '\n'.join(s[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(s), max_width))`

Comment: @stef: the join is best. But `i % k + 1` is never 0 for non-negative i and k. Try `i % max_width + 1 == max_width`. Or `i % max_width = max_width - 1`, which is maybe what was meant.

Comment: Hint: what is the last character that should appear on the first line? You want to put the `\n` immediately after that, right? So - when that character is found, what is the value of `i`? What is the value of `i % max_width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like this for a wrap of 4:

```
letter      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J   K   L   M   N   O ...
index       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14 ...
modulo      0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1   2   3   0   1   2 ...
mod(idx+1)  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2   3   0   1   2   3 ...
```

So, you want to wrap when the modulo equals `max_width-1` (here 3), or maybe easier to get, when **`modulo(index+1)` equals `0`**:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        result += string[i]
        if (i+1) % max_width == 0:
            result += '\n'
    
    return result

print(wrap('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 4))
```

output:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
QRST
UVWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to get characters along with their position. You cna also tell it to start at 1 which will make the modulo operation work on the appropriate breaking indexes:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    result = ''
    for i,c in enumerate(string,1):
        result += c
        if i % max_width == 0:
            result += '\n'        
    return result
```

alternatively, you could use a striding subscript to break down the string into chunks and assemble them using join:

```
def wrap(string, width):
    return "\n".join(string[i:i+width] for i in range(0,len(string),width))
```

or combine the logic into a single comprehension fed to the join funciton:

```
def wrap(string, width):
    return "".join(c+"\n"[i%width:] for i,c in enumerate(string,1))
```